# Contiguous Array Using Dequeue

Tags: java

I wanted to see if someone could help me understand this code. In particular, how does the variable/paramter "Integer" work in this. I would think that when it is being shown in the Dequeue and HashSet implementation that it is meant to represent the integer type. However, later the term "Integer" is being used to determine the value of the variable max. Can someone please provide clarity on how this portion of the code is working. This is meant to be a solution to the problem from HackerRank for Dequeues. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-dequeue/problem (in particular we are trying to determine the largest number of unique values possible in contiguous subarrays given a certain set of values).

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int input = in.nextInt();

            deque.add(input);
            set.add(input);

            if (deque.size() == m) {
                if (set.size() > max) max = set.size();
                int first = deque.remove();
                if (!deque.contains(first)) set.remove(first);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact question, Do you want explanation behind logic or anything else in the code. If code then - Please edit your code part to indicate specific section you want clarity about.

Comment: Can you explain how this "Integer" class is being used throughout this code to solve the problem? In particular the             HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(); and int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE portions of the code

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain all the use cases of Integer class in this code.

Comment: Also don't forget to accept /upvote my ans if you think it clarify you doubt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet instantiate `max` value as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, `MIN_VALUE` is a `static` field of Integer class which is the `lowest` possible value of Integer possible in java.

Instantiating max with MIN_VALUE makes sure that any other value which the code logic determine will anyway will be `more` that this. Technically speaking initialising `max` with `0` would have not changed the logic of the code. Because any way unique number will be more that 0 for now empty initial list.

`Integer` at other places like `Deque<Integer>` & `HashSet<Integer>` is placeholder for java generics, which basically mean what kind of element you are going to put in `Deque` and `Hashset`.

Comment: Ok - so is this being done just to initialize the value?

Comment: Yes initialising your max value with least possible integer!

Comment: Is there any specific perofrmance reasons why this is being done vs just setting it to 0 ?

Comment: No there is no performance gain or loss, It mostly a common practice to initialise values with `MIN_VALUE` if they are tend to **increase** and `MAX_VALUE` if they are tend to **decrease**.

Comment: Ok - and can you describe how it plays into generics? If you know it is going to be an integer value then you don't need to worry about generics in this case - correct? What other classes are used for generics for different types?

Comment: Classes such as Hashset can hold any kind of class instances. The way they are created basically makes it possible to store any kind of class object, This is how generics work in java. You yourself can create datastructures which meant to store any kind of data in it. However as java is strongly typed you will need to specify what kind of objects you are going to store upfront at the time of initiation of such generic classes. for more clarity you can read about generics here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Ok - is it true or false to say: Dequeue<Integer> and HashSet<Integer> can take any type or value as its parameter but it will just be wrapped in the Integer class ultimately?

Comment: No it's not true. Once created you can only add variable of type Integer in it. If you make it  HashSet<String> then you can only add objects of String class only.

Comment: Sorry - so why not just declare it as Dequeue<integer> with the lowercase "integer"?

Comment: Because you can use only classes for generics nothing else. Integer is a class not integer :) Also primitive types are not allowed in generics. Generics is not a trivial topic and will take some time to understand its implementation details, Take out some time to read about it in detail here - docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the Integer class
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 1):

`Deque<Integer>` and `HashSet<Integer>` in Java are generic data types. The Integer in angular brackets specify which type of data should these data structures contain. Declaring `Deque<Integer>` means that all elements inside the dequeue are of type Integer. Similarly if you want to store other data types such as strings or double, this can be done by declaring it as `Deque<String>` or `Deque<Double>`.

As for the

```java
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

the Integer class contains a constant variable named MIN_VALUE which is equal to -2^31.

Comment: Ok - is it true or false to say: Dequeue<Integer> and HashSet<Integer> can take any type or value as its parameter but it will just be wrapped in the Integer class ultimately?

Comment: Yes, the values will be wrapped by whichever class is specified as the type.